# How does a Hunter Beastmaster's Beast Companion level?

Tags: dnd-4e

How does a Beast Companion level? The only thing I know for sure is that my wolf (Hellhound) gets 8hp per lvl, but what about the other stats like strength, dex, cha, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You add your level to all of their stats. [For example](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/companion.aspx?id=90), here is the stat block for the horse companion:

> **Ability Scores:** Strength 14, Constitution 14, Dexterity 16, Intelligence 6, Wisdom 12, Charisma 6
>   **Size:** Medium or Large (you choose at creation, but must be one size larger than you if you want to use the Mount ability).
>   **Speed:** 10 squares
>   **Defenses:** AC 14 + level, Fortitude 13 + level, Reflex 12 + level, Will 12 + level
>   **Hit Points:** 14 + 8 per level
>   **Attack Bonus:** Level + 4
>   **Damage:** 1d8
>   **Melee Basic Attack:** Hooves; level + 4 vs. AC; 1d8 + Strength modifier damage.
>   **Trained Skill:** Endurance